# Can I export a subset of database (in a new MDF file) using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

My application uses a database in SQL Server. That database has tables, stored procedures, functions etc. Sometimes I need to give `MyDatabase.MDF` file to my clients. And here is the problem: I don't want to give all the tables to my clients, but only some of them. Also for some tables, I just want to give only a subset of their columns. Not only this, I also want to change the data so that confidential information does not get out.

So what I want: I have a config file as below:

- Tables that can be exported: `Employees, Contact Details. Department` etc.
- Columns that can be exported: `Employees<Name, DateOfBirth>, Contact Details<Phone>`
- Columns whose data is to be changed: `Employees<DateOfBirth>`

From above configuration file you can infer that I just want Employees, Contact Details. Department tables to be get exported (database can have other tables also). Employees have many columns but I just want Name, DateOfBirth columns to be get exported. And I want to change the values of DateOfBirth cloumn in Employees table.

So I want to create a new `.MDF` file (from the original one). That MDF file should meet some or all of the below requirements:

1. Only those tables get exported in new `.MDF` file, that I specify in the config file.
2. Only those columns get exported in new `.MDF` file, that I specify in the config file. If there is no entry for a particular table in the config file, I can then export all its columns.
3. If there are some columns in config file whose values I want to change, it should be possible.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? If all three requirements cannot be met, is it possible to meet one or two requirements? If yes, how can I do that? And Can I do that by creating a stored procedure (and not using C# or something else as I will prefer to use T-SQL only)

Please help.

Comment: I think the big intermediate step is to use your SP to programmatically create a new DATABASE (based off of the config) and hence the resulting mdf/ldf files.  I might not create a stored procedure for this but rather a SQLCMD script to run as necessary.  You haven't mentioned anything that can not be scripted.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I don't know anything about SQLCMD script but you have given me a direction. I'll search that and hopefully it will resolve my problem. Thanks a lot mate.